# CSS background repeating linear gradient

Tags: css

Can anyone please explain the "0 / 15px 15px" at the end of the following css property?

```
background: repeating-linear-gradient(45deg, #2b2b2b 0%, #2b2b2b 10%, #222222 0%, #222222 50%) 0 / 15px 15px;
```

[Source](http://codepen.io/FelixRilling/pen/qzfoc?editors=1100#0)

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/background#Values `bg-size`

Comment: thank you @Petrioli

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a shorthand equivalent to:

```
background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(45deg, #2b2b2b 0%, #2b2b2b 10%, #222222 0%, #222222 50%)
background-position-x: 0;
background-size: 15px 15px;
```

since `background-position` and `background-size` can both handle values like `15px 15px` or `0`, the slash provides a way for the browser to differentiate between the two. `Position` should always come before `size` [as defined in the spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#the-background).

Comment: Does that includes the '/' symbol also? Please tell about the significance of slash here.

Comment: @srikanthsharma I've updated my answer with more details